# Prove that an abelian group is direct sum of two subgroups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, direct-sum

I am trying to do this exercise:

> Let $G$ be an abelian group of order $mn$, where $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime. If
> $H_1 =\{x \in G: mx = 0\}$ and $H_2 =\{x \in G: nx = 0\}$, prove that $G=H_1  \oplus H_2$.

By proving that the intersection of $H_1$ and $H_2$ is the trivial subgroup; I have managed to prove that the sum (it is an additive group, althoght that is not important) is direct. However I can not prove the equality of $G$ and the direct sum. How should I approach that? (What I struggle with is the case in which the order of an element of $G$ does not divide either $m$ nor $n$).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See the [Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Groups.](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fundamental_Theorem_of_Finite_Abelian_Groups)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Write $1=am+bn$ for some integers $a,b$. Then, for each $x \in G$, $x=m(ax)+n(bx)$ and $mG \subset H_2$, $nG \subset H_1$.

Answer (score 0):

The number of element of the direct sum of $H_1$ and $H_2$ is the number of elements of $G$

Comment: Since the sum is direct, the order of the sum is equal to the product of the order of the subgroups. But, how do you calculate the order of the subgroups?